# How to add multiple registries in a table mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:

```
Users
uid [pk]

Transactions
uid[fk]
amount
```

With a one to many relation between both of the tables, so now I want to add all the transactions for every user and show them in a table like this:
UID -> balance

Idon't really know how can I make do this for every user in my table...
Any ideas?

I don't want to store the results, I just want to show them on a table, and after that I'll export that table to Excel.

Answer (score 1):

This SQL query will do the trick:

```
SELECT uid, SUM(amount) FROM Transactions GROUP BY uid
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the best solution for me :)